# Anne Pro 2 usb keyboard not working at login screen Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, usb, 20.04, keyboard, login-screen

I recently bought an Anne Pro 2 keyboard. The keyboard works straight away when plugged. But after a startup or reboot the USB device disappears. lsusb does not list the keyboard until I unplug en re-plug the keyboard.

The keyboard does work in the bios and grub.

When RGB of the keyboard is enabled I see the keyboard light up when the computer is turned on. After the grub, during boot sequence, the RGB turns off and when entering the login screen the keyboard will not work. The RGB will go momentarily but until I unplugged and re-plug the keyboard it will not work.

WORKAROUND: If I press any-key during boot BEFORE the login screen, than the keyboard will work.

Does anybody have a fix for the Anne Pro 2 specifically or how can I forcefully re-initialize a USB device during every (re)boot?

Thanks!

Comment: Greetings! Were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: No, I switched to a different keyboard.